# Script to clear a range but keep formulas - Gsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Specifically, I need a script to help me clear values from multiple rows but without clearing the formulas on those rows.

I have tried .clearContent which seems to just clear the whole row altogether without any option to keep the formulas.

I know that there might be some add-on that could help on a single sheet but I need to apply the procedure on multiple sheets so I would like to use a script for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the data used is a log from an ImportHtml with formulas inserted inbetween to produce a result. 
And some of the data are not relevant anymore as I am going to list the highest values in another sheet.

Comment: As the data is going to change on a daily basis but I am probably only going to update it weekly, I don't want to lose the formulas as I would have to re-enter them on 20+ sheets.

Comment: More elegant solution from @Chris S here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783968/google-spreadsheets-resetting-cells-while-keeping-mathematical-functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`range.getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()) to store your formulas, then call `range.clearContent()`, finally paste the formulas back with [`range.setFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String)).

Comment: Thank you. This solution has worked for what I intended to do.